# horizontal line between images using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble to put in horizontal lines between 2 images. Not sure how to go about doing this as I have just started learning Bootstrap.

I would like to achieve like the below image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vJdm.png

Comment: What have you currently tried? can you put up a jsfiddle?

Comment: post a demo be better

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at this code will be useful for you

```
<style>

 img{
    width:10%;
    display:inline-block;
    }

    .col-lg-5, .col-lg-2{
      padding-left:0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
    }


</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5" style="text-align:right">
             <img src="path/img1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <img src="path/img2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Based on the size of the image(default) you can change `width` and `col-lg-, col-md-, col-sm-, col-xs-` values and also **CSS**. Its working fine for me.